# Two dimensional Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

Tags: statistical-significance, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, c++

For a one dimensional Kolmogorov-Smirnov test there is a theoretical result, one can compare his or her test results directly by theoretical one, which is infinite sum (notice this formula is for big samples http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test ), and this distribution is called a Kolmogorov distribution. And one can compute the significance level (p-value) directly from this CDF formula. Also it's possible to get a probability density distribution from this formular and many other things.

So my question : Is there a theoretical result for 2 dimensional distributions ? Or, if I compute a 2 dimensional kolmogorov-smirnov test myself, by code that I have written myself, how can I check the quality of my test result? In this case I would prefer to have theoretical information.

Comment: There are some difficulties with a 2-D KS test. How exactly does your code work? (I don't want to see code, I want to understand what you told it to do - e.g. how do you compute the statistic?)

Comment: As you know also this test has computational problems, but I've reduced the complexity of test, so I just compute on several points on the plane , and it's enough for Kolmogorov-Smirnov stastitics, but anyway there's nothing to compare with my results? At least any literature . !!!! Any table for big samples . !!! And also what do you mean by saying complexity, you mean there are no theory about 2 dimension??  I know that In cosmology , theoretical physicists use 2 dimensional kolmogorov-smirnov test , so how they compare their results ?? A lot of questions :)   Thanks for response .

Comment: Your first sentence is unclear. Yes, literature on multidimensional KS tests can readily be found.

Comment: I dont think so . Can you say at least on source about two dimensional Kolmogorov-Smirnov test ? I mean theoretical results, not how to compute it . The first sentence ofcourse is unclear , because this is a long story to explain it properly . Thanks a lot .

Comment: An example of a paper ...  http://halweb.uc3m.es/esp/Personal/personas/dpena/articles/kolpl97.pdf

Comment: yes I know about it  very well. But the point is here is the method of computing it not theory of 2 dimensional test. I think people can do it in another way , of course someone can have not optimised way to compute it , but I'm very interested in theory of this test as we have one dimensional kolmogorov distribution for big samples. So it turns out we dont have any theoretical result for this case ? ? ?

Comment: Sorry once more question , do you know why in this article when they give an algorithm to compute statistic consisted of 5 parts, let's say in second and also in 3rd part they compute min then take 2/n-min or in 3rd part 1/n-min ,     Is not it the same just to compute max in these points    e.g. 1/n-min(on points)=max(on the same points)   ??? ??? ??? I'll be very grateful to hear an answer of this question

Comment: We have the result that there's no distribution free KS test for the two dimensional case; we don't even have a unique way of computing the largest in cdfs (you can define a way for a particular statistic, but it won't be the only choice).  Papers on extending the KS test to more than one dimension have to overcome those hurdles; a variety of ideas are employed in different papers. Some papers claim to have an approach that's nearly distribution free.

Comment: As you said some papers claim to have an approach , can you give some information about one of these papers. Thanks

Comment: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1987MNRAS.225..155F --- (but for a different - perhaps overstated - view, see https://asaip.psu.edu/Articles/beware-the-kolmogorov-smirnov-test)